# Replace placeholder in nested dict with values of mapping dict

Tags: dictionary, nested, string-formatting, python-3.5

I have a nested dict, which can contain placeholders in both keys and values.

```
example_dict = {'dict1': {'%(map3)s': {'data': 'tmp'},
                                 '%(map2)s': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}},
             'dict2': {'%(map3)s': {'data': '%(map1)s'}, '%(map3)s': {'status': 'available'}}}
```

I have a mapping dict, with the placeholder mapping:

```
mapping_dict= {
    "map1": [1,2,2],
    "map2": "qwerz",
    "map3": "asdfasdf"
}
```

If the placeholder is at a VALUE position, it can also happen that the corresponding mapping of the mapping_dict contains another datatype than a string as value, e.g. list or an int. How can I pass this datatype to the original dict? I don't know howto make a placeholder e.g. for a list.

**Info**: It can happen that the mapping_dict contains more keys than the given example_dict contains.

I would like to have a function which replaces the placeholders of a given dict with the values of the mapping_dict.

What would be a good recursive implementation for this?

Comment: this is a simple (a) iterate-on-base-type, (b) inspect-item-type, (c) goto a; until you get to a string or a non-iterable type... what is the problem you're having?

Comment: A list can't be a dictionary key. Except if you're going to use the list's string representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a stack to navigate the key value pairs, you can pop out keys to rename them and for the values, do the same except try and see if you can evaluate them as Python literals using `ast.literal_eval` to handle your list case.

```
import ast
from copy import deepcopy

example_dict = {
    'dict1': {
        '%(map3)s': {'data': 'tmp'},
        '%(map2)s': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}
    },
    'dict2': {
        '%(map3)s': {'data': '%(map1)s'}
    }
}

mapping_dict= {
    "map1": [1,2,2],
    "map2": "qwerz",
    "map3": "asdfasdf"
}

def sub_placeholders(orig, subs):
    d = deepcopy(orig)
    todo = [d]
    while todo:
        nxt = todo.pop()
        for k, v in nxt.items():
            nxt[k % mapping_dict] = nxt.pop(k)
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                todo.append(v)
            elif isinstance(v, str):
                nxt[k] = v % subs
                try:
                    nxt[k] = ast.literal_eval(nxt[k])
                except ValueError:
                    pass
    return d
```

Running `sub_placeholders(example_dict, example_mapping)` will give you:

```
{'dict1': {'asdfasdf': {'data': 'tmp'}, 'qwerz': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}},
 'dict2': {'asdfasdf': {'data': [1, 2, 2]}}}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is one recursive option deleting the existing keys and adding new keys them applying the "format" with "named" placeholders. Note: we are modifying the input dictionary in this case:

```
from pprint import pprint

example_dict = {'dict1': {'%(map1)s': {'data': 'tmp'}, '%(map2)s': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}},
                'dict2': {'%(map1)s': {'data': '%(map1)s'}, '%(map2)s': {'status': 'available'}}}

mapping_dict= {
    "map1": "asdf",
    "map2": "qwerz",
}


def apply_placeholder(d, placeholder):
    for key, value in d.items():
        del d[key]
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d[key % placeholder] = value
            apply_placeholder(value, placeholder)
        else:
            d[key % placeholder] = value % placeholder


apply_placeholder(example_dict, mapping_dict)
pprint(example_dict)
```

Prints:

```
{'dict1': {'asdf': {'data': 'tmp'}, 'qwerz': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}},
 'dict2': {'asdf': {'data': 'asdf'}, 'qwerz': {'status': 'available'}}}
```

I don't particularly like the `del` calls and modifying the input object here and would be happy to see a better option.

Comment: Can you make use of `dict.pop` here?

Comment: @NinjaPuppy I feel like I'm on an interview, just presented a poor solution and an interviewer is trying to help me pointing me into the right direction :)

Comment: Sorry - didn't mean it like that :)

Comment: Nono, it's just my personal fear/phobia and occasional thematic nightmares.

Comment: Just a additional question: What do I need to change, if the mapping_dict contains a number (int) or a list (with int) and I also want to have the correct datatype in the input dict?

Comment: @eljobso sure, a quick fix would be to replace `d[key % placeholder] = value % placeholder` with `d[key % placeholder if isinstance(key, str) else key] = value % placeholder if isinstance(value, str) else value`. In this case though, we may sometimes recreate items that don't need to be processed (say a key and a value are integers).

Comment: @eljobso please wait for other options. I have a strong feeling there is a better solution making a new dictionary instead of modifying the existing one.

Comment: Sure no worries, I updated the question (inkl. code example) regarding my additional question. The code you posted in your previous comment unofrtunately does not put the list as a list in the example dict, it makes a string out of it.

Comment: @eljobso that's quite a change in requirements - you're no longer after string substitution but element substitution...

Comment: To be honest, when I was asking the question, I totally forgot about that case. I changed the title of the question and added information. Sorry for the circumstances.

Comment: @alecxe I've posted an answer at my stab of doing it if you're interested - although I'm sure it still needs some work :p

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you want, recursively. It creates a copy of the original dictionary and then modifies that so original can be reused.

```
from pprint import pprint
import copy

try:
    stringtype = basestring
except NameError:
    stringtype = str  # Python 3

def subst(mapping, replacements):

    def do_subst(mapping, replacements):
        for k, v in list(mapping.items()):
            newk, newv = k, v
            changed = False

            if isinstance(k, stringtype):
                newk = k % replacements
                if newk != k:
                    changed = True

            if isinstance(v, stringtype):
                newv = v % replacements
                if newv != v:
                    changed = True
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                newv = do_subst(v, replacements)
                if newv != v:
                    changed = True

            if changed:
                del mapping[k]
                mapping[newk] = newv

        return mapping

    return do_subst(copy.deepcopy(mapping), replacements)

example_dict = {'dict1': {'%(map1)s': {'data': 'tmp'},
                          '%(map2)s': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}},
                'dict2': {'%(map1)s': {'data': '%(map1)s'},
                          '%(map2)s': {'status': 'available'}}}

mapping_dict= {"map1": "asdf", "map2": "qwerz"}

print('Before')
pprint(example_dict)
result = subst(example_dict, mapping_dict)
print('After')
pprint(result)
```

Output:

```
 Before
 {'dict1': {'%(map1)s': {'data': 'tmp'}, '%(map2)s': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}},
  'dict2': {'%(map1)s': {'data': '%(map1)s'},
            '%(map2)s': {'status': 'available'}}}
 After
 {'dict1': {'asdf': {'data': 'tmp'}, 'qwerz': {'freshdata': 'testtest'}},
  'dict2': {'asdf': {'data': 'asdf'}, 'qwerz': {'status': 'available'}}}
```